# How to test DropDownPicker? Any examples?

Tags: react-native-dropdown-picker

I am trying to write tests using '@testing-library/react-native' for the DropDownPicker. Any examples as once I fireEvent press I cannot find a way to find any of the drop down list items. I have already added a testID for each item.